# Keep audio streaming in WebView even after app gets killed by system

Tags: android, audio, android-webview, android-service

I have an app which uses a `WebView` to show a page playing live audio streams from a radio.
The audio streams are played through and `<audio />` tag on the web page.

The problem is if I switch between too many apps, or let the phone screen locked for more than 5 minutes, android kills my app / the `WebView`, and the audio playback stops.

Is there a way to keep the audio stream alive even if the app is killed, and then re-open the `WebView` at the same state (or at least url) than when it was killed?

Or the only way is to build a native player running inside a `Service` ?

Comment: If I did it, I'd parse out the stream and played it suing Android service

Comment: Yeah that could be an idea. You would have to prevent the WebView from playing it's own stream no? How can you do that?

Comment: you can add listener (via JS for example) to trigger when page load finishes, find the audio tag, parse it an remove from the page

Comment: Thank you, it's not the simplest solution, but maybe the only one.